# Llamar una variable de laravel a js

Tags: javascript, html, laravel

Buenas estoy intentando mostrar un iframe dentro de un foreach y necesito pasar el id de cada item. Si pongo el id manual poniendo un numero id de la tabla funciona a la perfección, pero mi interés seria pasarle una variable para no tenerlo que hacer manualmente... expongo mi codigo:

El numero 16 seria el id manual y lo que yo quiero es pasarle la variable esta echactamente:
{{$comment->id}} pero no logro hacerlo...

```js
function postYourAdd () {
 var iframe = $("#forPostyouradd_" + 16);
 iframe.attr("src", iframe.data("src")); 
}
```

al clicar el boton se veria el iframe:

```
<button onclick="postYourAdd()" type="button">
show content
</button>
 
<iframe id="forPostyouradd_{{$comment->id}}" data-src="{{route('reactions.show', ['id' => $comment->id])}}" src="about:blank" width="500" height="200" style="background:#ffffff"></iframe>
```

Comment: No logras hacerlo porque confundes variables creadas en el servidor (Laravel) con métodos del cliente (Javascript). Para obtener las variables de forma dinámica en Javascript, necesitas pedirlas al servidor. Lo usual es mediante llamadas Ajax. Otra forma sería enviar las variables dentro de la estructura `html` de tu documento, para ello puedes usar el atributo `id`o algún atributo `data-*`. Saludos

Comment: Gracias por responder! Me cuesta mucho js y he estado buscando y lo que debo es pasarle en element id... como puedo hacerlo?